# Big text file processing

Tags: import, wolfram-mathematica, text-processing

I need to implement lazy loading in Mathematica. I have a 600 Mb CSV text file which I need to process. This file contains a lot of duplicated records:

```
1;0;0;13;6
1;0;0;13;6
..........
2;0;0;13;6
2;0;0;13;6
..........
etc.
```

So instead of loading them all into memory, I'd like to create a list containing records and the number of times this record was encountered in the file:

```
{{10000,{1,0,0,13,6}}, {20000,{2,0,0,13,6}}, ...}
```

I couldn't find a way to do it with Import function. I'm looking for something like

```
Import["my_file.csv", "CSV", myProcessingFunction]
```

where myProcessingFunction will take one record at a time and create a dataset. Is it possible to do this with Import or any other Mathematica function?

Comment: In case you don't know, this is called Run Length Encoding. There are several neat Mathematica algorithms for implementing it.

Comment: @Tim Kemp: before running an algorithm I need to load the data first. The size of the data does not allow it to be loaded at once. My question is about how to load the data line by line, rather than about how to group the records. Also RLE algorithms preserve the sequence of records. I don't need this. I only need the counts. For instance AAABBBBAAAA after RLE becomes 3A,4B,4A. I need 7A, 4B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it were me, I'd probably do this using unix `sort` and `uniq`, but since you ask about Mathematica.... I'd use ReadList[] to read blocks of lines, and define downvalues to find the unique strings an keep track of how many we've seen before.

```
(* Create some test data *)
Export["/tmp/test.txt", Flatten[{Range[1000], Range[1000]}], "Lines"];

countUniqueLines[file_String, blockSize_Integer] := Module[{stream, map, block, keys, out}, 
    map[_]:=0;
    stream = OpenRead[file];
    CheckAbort[While[(block=ReadList[stream, String, blockSize])=!={}, 
        (map[#]=map[#]+1)& /@ block;];, Close[stream];Clear[map]];
    Close[stream];
    keys = Cases[DownValues[map][[All, 1, 1, 1]], _String];
    out = {#, map[#]}& /@ keys;
    Clear[map];
    out
]

countUniqueLines["/tmp/test.txt", 500]


(* Alternative implementation if you have a little more memory *)
Tally[Import["/tmp/test.txt", "Lines"]]
```

Comment: +1, definitely the approach I'd take. Three things. The while loop needs to be wrapped in a `CheckAbort`, otherwise the stream will be left open when. This is vital when dealing with a large file. Secondly, the semicolon must be included in `WordSeparators`, or it will generate a lot of errors with a CSV file.  Lastly, how well does it behave with a 600 mb file?

Comment: @rcollyer, I added the CheckAbort handling.  This function processes lines only; it doesn't separate the fields which saves some memory.  It should be as simple as changing ReadList to break on ";", though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the `Read[]` function.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there are better alternatives than Mathematica for doing this.

A small awk script:

```
 {a[$0]++}  
 END { ... print loop ... }
```

will accumulate the repeated records. Of course you may suffer overflows depending on the number of distinct records.

Or **sort** the file first and the counting will not overflow. In awk, the non-overflows program may be something like;

```
 BEGIN{ p =""; i=0}

 {if (($0 != p) &&  (i != 0) ) {print $0,i ; p =$0; i=0; next}}

 {i++; p = $0}
```

Perhaps Perl is better, but I'm old fashioned.

HTH!

Comment: And you can of course call awk or perl from within Mathematica.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to consider loading it first into a database system like MySQL and then you can access it from *Mathematica* using the DatabaseLink.